# Click como se fosse toggle ou hover

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

Estou com um problema em algo similar a um tooltip legado, o que acontece é que fizeram no hover desta forma:

```
var elem  = jQuery('#interrogacao_adicionar_cartao_div');
jQuery('#tooltip-cartao').hover(
    function() {
        elem.show();
    }, function() {
        elem.hide();
    }
);
```

Ele funciona porem em mobile ele não some, ta é por que mobile é touch etc

Então estou mudando para que seja click tanto desktop e mobile, eu vi que tem outras formas mais simples de se fazer etc, mas eu não posso mudar nada apenas o evento que exibe e remove devido a estar em milhares de lugares e tem que funcionar de forma igual entre desktop e mobile

Então se clicar no `#tooltip-cartao` ele exibe e se ele ja estiver aberto e clicar nele ou em qualquer outro elemento fechar

Fiz da forma abaixo:

```
var click = jQuery('#tooltip-cartao');
var elem  = jQuery('#interrogacao_adicionar_cartao_div');
var att   = '';

jQuery('#tooltip-cartao , body').click(function(){
    att   = click.data('active');
    if (att === 'disable' && jQuery(this).attr('id') == 'tooltip-cartao') {
        click.attr('data-active','enable');
        elem.show();

    } else if (att === 'enable') {
        click.attr('data-active','disable');            
        elem.hide();                
    }
});
```

O problema que ele acaba pegando 2 eventos ao mesmo tempo então ele fica sempre mostrando ou sempre fechado pois não consigo juntar os 2 eventos em apenas um

```
Obs: não posso usar toggle por que não funciona em iphone 4 e 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar `body`, é melhor usar `document` que abrange todo o HTML, enquanto o `body` se restringe apenas à área onde há conteúdo.

O exemplo abaixo mostra o conceito, então você deve adaptar ao seu código:

```js
$(document,'#tooltip-cartao').click(function(e){
  if($("#div").is(":visible")){
      $("#div").hide();
   }else if(e.target.tagName != "HTML"){
      $("#div").show();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="tooltip-cartao" type="button" value="mostrar DIV" />
<div id="div" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow; display: none; padding: 10px;">
   Olá! Clique em qualquer lugar para fechar
</div>
```